# REST-assured with Spock and Groovy

Tags: groovy, spock, rest-assured

I am new to Spock and would like to write tests for a REST interface with Spock and REST-assured. Knowing REST-assurend in conjunction with Java I would like how to use REST-assured with Spock. Can anyone provide an example for this?

Comment: you can usually write spock tests alot like you would with junit.  so what exactly is your question here?  what have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually I would like to understand how to combine REST-assured given()/when()/then() with Spocks blocks at best. For someone new to Groovy it is not so obvious.

Comment: as spock already provide the same names as keywords, it will be confusing.  you could check how e.g. [geb](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/testing.html#spock_junit__testng) integrates with spock.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand why my question is related to "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource". 

If you apply this to my question you can close 95% of all questions on this sie.

Answer (score 4):

REST-Assured's DSL seems at odds with Spock's DSL. Potential solutions are to adapt the former  (e.g. using Groovy extension methods), or to put all code into a single `expect:` block.